# android: dynamically creating views and access them later

Tags: android

In android i am creating a form with multiple textinputlayout and textinputedit views.

The form data I get from JSON.

I have an empty linearLayout

```
linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.email_login_form);
```

looping over form fields provided by JSON

loop start

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout= new TextInputLayout(MainActivity.this);
TextInputLayout.setLayoutParams(new TextInputLayout.LayoutParams(TextInputLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TextInputLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
TextInputEditText textInputEditText = new TextInputEditText(MainActivity.this);
textInputEditText.setHint(label);
TextInputLayout.addView(textInputEditText);
linearLayout.addView(textInputLayout);
```

loop end

Now if we see I am creating TextinputLayout and inside i am creating textInputEditText for each field and adding them to the linear layout.

How to store them and later access them, because i have to get their input values and submit the form

Comment: Try to set listeners while creating it and get their input values from listeners.

Comment: Add them to a `List` or an array, assign them unique IDs and use `findViewById()`, loop over the `LinearLayout`'s child `View`s with `getChildCount()` and `getChildAt()`, etc. Several different ways to do it, and plenty of examples already on-site.

Comment: Just save them in a collection . And use them by index .

Comment: @Mike how to ensure they are assigned unique ids. If i store them in a list will i still have to access them using findviewbyID().

Comment: `View.generateViewId()`, a loop counter, etc. That's probably the least preferable option, though, 'cause then you have to track the IDs, too.

Comment: If you keep them in a `List`, no, you don't need `findViewById()`. You have direct access to them through the `List`; e.g., with `get(index)`, an `Iterator`, etc.

Comment: Is it a good idea to create dynamic forms. Because in future i want to add or remove some form fields from backend. I was looking for more flexible way to do it. SO i was trying this.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with it. It's a must for many situations, and yours sounds like one. Many of Android's built-in components already do this exact same thing – e.g., `ListView`, `RecyclerView`, etc. – it's just abstracted away into `Adapter`s and layouts. If you want to do it all in code yourself, go nuts. In some ways, it's actually easier to do certain things like that.

Comment: Just store the values in any collection variable.

Comment: @Mike. You mean i have to use a recyclerview instead of linearLayout inside a scrollview.

Comment: No, I was just saying that dynamic forms are very common, though the framework does the heavy lifting for you in the components most users are familiar with. Those were just examples in response to your question "Is it a good idea to create dynamic forms".

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to store anything extra.

You can just iterate through the children of your `linearLayout`.

All is there.